# How to get Selected option Text of ng-option

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have this drop-down list in my angular code:

**HTML:**

```
<select class="selected_location" ng-options="perlocation.id as perlocation.name for perlocation in locations" ng-model="cleaningServiceLocation">


           <option value="">Please Select Location</option>


</select> 


<p>{{cleaningServiceLocation}}</p>
```

**Render:**

```
<select class="selected_location" ng-options="perlocation.id as perlocation.name for perlocation in locations" ng-model="cleaningServiceLocation">

<option value="" class="" selected="selected">Please Select Location</option>
<option value="string:loc1" label="Location Name">Location Name</option>
<option value="string:loc2" label="Other Name">Other Name</option>


</select>
```

When ever user selection option i need to get Option inner Text like "Location Name".

But we get option value like "loc1"

Answer (score 0):

Change `perlocation.id as perlocation.name` to `perlocation.name`. The first one means you display perlocation.name, and its value is perlocation.id.

Comment: Yes we display perlocation.name and values as perlocation.id.

Comment: I mean, you should do this `ng-options="perlocation.name as perlocation.name for perlocation in locations"`